# How do I type a backtick on a Danish keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

How do I type a backtick in Windows on a Danish keyboard?

It is this fellow:

```
`
```

You can get it by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>96</kbd> on the numberic keyboard, but that is less than ideal.

Comment: See [Danish Keyboard Layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/kbdda.html).

Comment: ... It is Feb 2020 and I just googled this, clicked the answer and tried it out. Then I looked back at the page and realized who asked the question 2 years ago... Me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd> (the key between <kbd>?</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>)

You need to press <kbd>Space</kbd> or any other key for it to appear after pressing the above combination.

Comment: You will have to press space after that.